# Class_variable and instance_variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, exception, nameerror

```
class A:
    x=10
    def fn(self):
        print(x)
```

I tried running this code, but an error comes out as:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

inside the function block if i put self.x then it works perfectly
my doubt is why doesnt the above code work properly
x is defined in class scope,so shouldnt it be accessable to all functions defined in class as class_variable also

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names): *The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods*.  More details in the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Inside class it is a local variable, you can assign it to a property of the class and get it:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    x=10
    self.x = x
    def fn(self):
      print(self.x)
```